# Replacing the missing value Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-datareader

```
{'Country': 'USA', 'Age': '52', 'Sal': '12345', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'UK', 'Age': '23', 'Sal': '1142', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '4456', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '4456', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '?', 'Sal': '2345', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '3342', 'OnWork': 'Yes'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '25', 'Sal': '3452', 'OnWork': 'No'}
{'Country': 'MAL', 'Age': '?', 'Sal': '3562', 'OnWork': 'No'}
```

Here I have to replace the missing mean value bases on "OnWork" value. Group Yes and its mean value go to Row5 Age. Group NO and its value should go to the Last row.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Mycal.csv", na_values = missing_values, nrows=50)
```

## Find and replace the Mean value (This is working)

```
df["F8"].fillna(df['F8'].mean(), inplace=True)
```

## here I am able to find the Mean value, However I am not able to replace it.

```
df[df["Class"]=="Yes"]["F8"].mean()
```

I am expecting the Yes values should group and fill Missing value the Mean to fill same for NO. Kindly help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) as:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].mask(df['Age'].eq('?'), np.nan).astype(float)
df['Age'] = (df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby('OnWork')['Age'].transform(np.nanmean))
                      .astype(int))

print(df)
  Country  Age    Sal OnWork
0     USA   52  12345     No
1      UK   23   1142    Yes
2     MAL   25   4456     No
3     MAL   25   4456     No
4     MAL   24   2345    Yes
5     MAL   25   3342    Yes
6     MAL   25   3452     No
7     MAL   31   3562     No
```

If you want to replace multiple column values at once use:

```
df = df.fillna(df.groupby('OnWork').transform('mean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to replace missing values by average for each group, then here is one of the solution:

```
df_mean = df.groupby('Class')['F8'].mean().reset_index()
df_mean.columns = ['Class','F8_mean']
df = pd.merge(df, df_mean, on='Class', how='left')
df.loc[df['F8'].isnull(), 'F8'] = df['F8_mean']
df.drop('F8_mean', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use euclidean-distance formula to find the missing value on the same set of values?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import libries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Data dictionary
data_dict = {'Country': ['USA','UK','MAL','MAL','MAL','MAL','MAL','MAL'], 
              'Age': ['52','23','25','25','?','25','25','?'], 'Sal': ['12345','1142','4456','4456','2345','3342','3452','3562'], 
              'OnWork': ['No','Yes','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','No']} 

# Convert dictionary to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

# print input df
print(df)
```

**

```
       Country Age  Sal    OnWork
    0     USA  52  12345     No
    1      UK  23   1142    Yes
    2     MAL  25   4456     No
    3     MAL  25   4456     No
    4     MAL   ?   2345    Yes
    5     MAL  25   3342    Yes
    6     MAL  25   3452     No
    7     MAL   ?   3562     No
```

**

```
# '?' Values replace with NaN
df.Age=df.Age.where(df.Age!='?')

# Convert string values to numeric 
df["Age"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Age"])

# Get mean values Separately
mean_list = df.groupby('OnWork')['Age'].mean().astype(int)

# print mean values 
print(mean_list)
```

**

```
No     31
Yes    24
```

**

```
# Replace the missing age value 
df['Age'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: mean_list['Yes'] if np.isnan(row['Age'])&(row['OnWork']=='Yes')  else mean_list['No'] if np.isnan(row['Age'])&(row['OnWork']=='No') else row['Age'],
    axis=1
)

# print final df
print(df)
```

**

```
  Country   Age    Sal OnWork
0     USA  52.0  12345     No
1      UK  23.0   1142    Yes
2     MAL  25.0   4456     No
3     MAL  25.0   4456     No
4     MAL  24.0   2345    Yes
5     MAL  25.0   3342    Yes
6     MAL  25.0   3452     No
7     MAL  31.0   3562     No
```

**

Comment: Thank you Dinesh. I am looking for eulidean distance too. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Would start by adjusting the dataframe:

1. Replace the `?` with [`numpy.NaN`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.NAN)

   ```
   df.replace('?', np.nan, inplace=True)
   ```
2. Convert the `Age` column to numeric with [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

   ```
   df['Age'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Age'])
   ```

Then, with those changes, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`pandas.Series.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html) with a custom lambda function as follows

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby('OnWork')['Age'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean())).astype('int')

[Out]:

  Country  Age    Sal OnWork
0     USA   52  12345     No
1      UK   23   1142    Yes
2     MAL   25   4456     No
3     MAL   25   4456     No
4     MAL   24   2345    Yes
5     MAL   25   3342    Yes
6     MAL   25   3452     No
7     MAL   31   3562     No
```

**Notes:**

- `.astype('int')` is to make sure that the column `Age` is of integer type.